# How can I mount a REST API application as a drive?

Tags: node.js, rest, webdav, nfs

I have an application that has a public facing REST API. The application acts as  file manager that allows for  listing, deleting, uploading, and downloading of files. Right now a web based GUI sits on top of the api that looks like a typical file explorer.

However, I'm looking for a way to mount the application as a drive on windows (and possibly linux). So is there a piece of software I can use, or perhaps an open source project that I could modify that creates an NFS or WebDav share (or something else) on the top and would allow me to modify the bottom end to call my api?

I'm not sure if it's relevant, but the application is coded mostly in Node.js. Since it's a rest api, i'm open to anything sitting out in front of it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On Linux, you should use FUSE. Windows does not have such interface, as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: i think i'd prefer to start with windows. But if i were to use fuse, do you have any more details?

Comment: Well basically, you need to provide an interface in C which implements all file system calls (`write`, `read`, `open`, `stat`, ...). You can then register the interface in the kernel, and you should be able to mount your file system with the `mount` command.